# Debian Jessie shutdown on CTRL+ALT+DEL

Tags: debian, shutdown, systemd

For our Linux VM's in VirtualBox, we like to map `CTRL+ALT+DEL` to

```
shutdown -h now
```

The old way was editing the `inittab` file. How is this done now in Debian 8 with systemd?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just `cd` into `/lib/systemd/system/` and change the symlink of `ctrl-alt-del.target` from `reboot.target` to `poweroff.target`.

```
ln -s /lib/systemd/system/poweroff.target /etc/systemd/system/ctrl-alt-del.target
```

then reset systemd daemon:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there may be a [special](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html) target named `ctrl-alt-del.target`.
So, as [mailing list says](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2014/02/msg00824.html) you may just link the target to, say, `poweroff.target`